# http-proxy-middleware adds a '/' before query parameters

Tags: express, node-http-proxy, http-proxy-middleware

I want to consume an API using a proxy written in express. I use http-proxy-middleware for this. Here is the setup I have:

```
app.use(
  createProxyMiddleware('/api', {
    target: 'http://example.com/api/v2',
    changeOrigin: true,
    pathRewrite: {
      '/api': '',
    }
  })
);
```

Then I make a request from postman or browser: `GET http://localhost:8080/api/list?first=50`

All I get from the API server is 404. I saw in the browser that the URL changes to `http://localhost:8080/api/v2/list/?first=50` and I don't understand why.

All I want is to add an auth header which I managed to do using `onProxyReq`, but now I just want everything that comes after `/api` to be forwarded as is to `http://example.com/api/v2`.

Comment: What is the result of http://example.com/api/v2/list?first=50 ?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen When called directly through postman the request succeeds and the result is a JSON. When called through the proxy the result is also a JSON, but the content is `{ "summary": "Not found.", "status_code": 404 }`. The result is the same as when calling [example.com/api/v2/non/existing/path](http://example.com/api/v2/non/existing/path).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got it to work. Turns out I had some things wrong. The first wrong thing `target: 'http://example.com/api/v2'` should be `target: 'http://example.com'`. Then, `pathRewrite` will rewrite anything it matches and redirect to the new path, so it ended up calling `localhost:8080/api/list?first=50` and then `localhost:8080/api/v2/list/?first=50`. So with these 2 mistakes combined, in the end the API call would be `example.com/api/v2/v2/list/?first=50` and that's clearly wrong. I replaced the target and I am now using `/api/v2` as context for the proxy.

I would still like to call my proxy using `localhost:8080/api/whatever` and have it turned into `example.com/api/v2/whatever`, but it's just a nice to have.

Comment: I am using "http-proxy-middleware" on client side, but I need to pass path param to target how can I do that?